# E-commerce in CMSMS

Tags: php, e-commerce, cmsmadesimple

Is there any module to create a complete shopping cart application in cmcms? I mean product listing, cart and order tracking. i found something in net but it requires separate modules for each task like products, cart, order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The separate Products, Cart and Orders modules are still the way to go for ecommerce in CMSMS. Refer to this page for a decent HOWTO on how to make it all work together. It's been revised fairly recently, and written by the module developer.

http://calguy1000.com/Blogs/8/60/cmsms-quick-e-commerce-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following modules together several times:

**Calguys Ecommerce Base**
**Cart** (shopping cart)
**Products** (for the product catalog)
**Formbuilder** (for the order form)

There is also the Orders module, and several shipping rate modules. Everything ties together quite well, so I didn't mind that several separate modules were involved.
It's easy to customize everything to your need with some configuration and smarty-code.